# Calculate cosh(x) given sinh(x)

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Given the value of sinh(x)

for example `sinh(x) = 3/2`

How can I calculate the value of `cosh(x)` ?

Comment: Use identity: $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$

Comment: @alans When you hover your mouse over "add comment" you will see the following: *Use comments to ask for more information or to suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments**.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the identity $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x \equiv 1$. If $\sinh x = \frac{3}{2}$ then
$$\cosh^2x - \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\! 2} = 1$$
$$\cosh^2x - \frac{9}{4} = 1$$
$$\cosh^2x = \frac{13}{4}$$
It follows that $\cosh x = \pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{13}$. Since $\cosh x \ge 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\cosh x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: You made a sign error. $\sinh$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself.

Comment: I think you want $\sinh x = \frac{3}{2}$ in your premise, not $\sinh^2$. (I tried to edit but it wasn't substantial enough since it was only two characters.)

Comment: @IsmailBadawi You should not edit other people's posts.

Comment: @FlybyNight Stack Exchange disagrees with you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer

Answer (score 9):

The trick is....

$$\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Most books I have seen use this way to solve this problem using the same identity mentioned in the accepted answer:
$$\sqrt{1+\sinh^2x}=\cosh x$$

$\therefore \sqrt{1+(\frac{3}{2})^2}=\cosh x$

$ \frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}=\cosh x$

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$ you can evaluate it.

But unlike circular trig functions, there is only a *single value* for

$ \cosh( \sinh^{-1}(x)) $

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to say that $cosh^2x-sinh^2x=1$? Yes that is correct because of this:
$1/4[e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}-e^{2x}+2-e^{-2x}]= 1/4 \times 4=1$